# Writing random numbers to text file using c#

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I want to write random numbers to a text file.

But when i try to write the random numbers, i am able to write till 49 numbers and above 49 it overwrites all the numbers.
i am attaching my code below. Pls let me know how can i do it?

```
public void CreateRandomData(int lowerRange, int upperRange)
{ 
     Random r = new Random(); 
     int number = 0; 
     using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"c:\\test.txt"))
     {
         for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
         {
             number = r.Next(lowerRange, upperRange);
             writer.Write(number + ",");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. The code you've written will effectively delete the file contents first, due to calling `Create(...).Close()`. But it will only write 49 numbers anyway. Do you mean you just want to change the code to append to whatever's there? If so, get rid of the `File.Create(...).Close()` call.

Comment: It's stopping at 49 due to your for statement, use i <= 50. Additionally you don't need to Close a file create.

Comment: yes i want to append more than 49 numbers... in the for loop itself.  If i remove the file create line, then file will have previous text.

Comment: And if you want to increase performance by a few hundred times, place the for-loop _inside_ the `using(){}`

Comment: public void CreateRandomData(int lowerRange,int upperRange)
       {
           Random r = new Random();
           int number = 0;      
                         
               using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(@"c:\\test.txt"))                {
                                       
                    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        number = r.Next(lowerRange, upperRange);
                        writer.Write(number+",");                  
                   
                }

           }
          
          }

Comment: The above code does not work...

Comment: Pls give me code to append 100 random numbers to a file...Thats all...

Comment: Please tell us the actual code and problem that you are having! The new edited code seems to work fine. What's the problem?

Comment: The above code is the final code... it looks fine. but when it writes to file i get a output as  |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||.. its looks like overwritten

Comment: its not overwritten you are opening it with notepad and its got confused for some reason. open in visual studio or use my code and it will be fine

Comment: You totally removed the original question. Tht's not how this site is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok there are a few odd things about your code, but mainly seems to be overwriting the file each time you run the program

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            int lowerRange = 1;
            int upperRange = 10;
            string filename = @"c:\\development\test.txt";
            Random r = new Random();
            int number = 0;

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++)
                {
                    number = r.Next(lowerRange, upperRange);

                    writer.Write(number + ",");

                }
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Note to other readers :

While writing this I noticed that File.Append produced odd results when you opened the appended file in notepad. The data is appended but the file appears corrupt.

I assume this was due to either the writer not flushing or closing properly or using the wrong encoding.

However, I didn't really get to the bottom of this as the above code worked for whatever reason and doesn't use File.Append

Comment: obvs change the filename to one of your choice

Comment: tried and tested, please accept as the answer if it works for you

Comment: yes it works fine. But if i run the code 2 times.. previous data is retained in the file. I do not want that. I want initially a empty file which will be appended by random numbers for a execution

Comment: if the file is always empty at the start its not really appended to is it

Comment: ok ive updated so it makes a new file each time. (although your first code did this) also uped the number of random numbers to 500 in case that was your issue

Comment: it should append the numbers created in the loop. But not the previous execution values.   EG: run i<11 first then run i<16.. The file should have only 15 values not 10+15=25.

Comment: Note to other readers : while writing this I noticed that File.Append produced odd results when you opened the appended file in notepad. I assume this was sue to either the writer not flushing or closing properly or using the wrong encoding. However, I didnt really get to the bottom of this as the above code worked for whatever reason and doesnt use File.Append

Comment: @Jeev yes it does that now, adjust the i < 500 to the value of your choice

Answer (score 3):

You know you could just do this and make it simple:

```
public void CreateRandomData(int lowerRange, int upperRange)
{ 
    Random r = new Random();
    File.AppendAllText(@"c:\\test.txt", String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
        .Select(n => r.Next(lowerRange, upperRange))));
}
```

Comment: No. That's shorter but whether it's simpler depends on where you are on the learning curve.

Comment: I love the one line of linq answers, they are super l33t